# How to add headers to a httprequestmessage

Tags: c#

I would like to add headers to a HttpRequestMessage. Problem is HttpRequestHeaders has no constructor, HttpHeaders is abstract, ... .
Is there any way we can use these classes somewhere in our code ( I could use a  `List<Tuple<string, List<string>>` but does not look nice at all)

Answer (score 66):

An HttpRequestMessage already has an instance of HttpRequestHeaders, and you can not change it. You can add a header like this:

```cs
message.Headers.Add("X-Hello", "world");
```

Comment: Yes this is what i do internally in my function, but my function signature looks awfull . I have something like public static string Get(Uri url, Dictionary<string, List<string>> headers)

Comment: Why not just a Dictionary<string,string> headers ?

Comment: Yes I could probably do that (I have come accross once a website that was putting twice the same key in the headers). Furthermore the definition of HttpHeaders in .Net is `public abstract class HttpHeaders : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>, 
 IEnumerable`

Comment: You probably want a `NameValueCollection` or a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead of a dictionary, because headers can occur multiple times and the order may be of importance. I agree that using HttpHeaders would be nicer.

Answer (score 7):

You can get an empty instance of `HttpHeaders` in one of the following ways:

```
var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;
var headers = new HttpResponseMessage().Headers;
var headers = new HttpRequestMessage().Headers;
```

You could also make your own class that extends `HttpHeaders` and use that.