# Why am I getting unauthorised when the code looks fine to me in my step definition file

Tags: c#, automation, specflow

Trying to generate and API key but seem to get a unauthorised (status 401):

The client security is a company's own web security layer to allow the request to be generated.  Obviously these are just dummy keys for confidentiality, do you know what I am mising in the code which would make it a 401.  The keys have been taken from Postman and it works so I know the keys are valid.

```
[Given(@"create the APIKeyId")]
public async Task GivenCreateTheAPIKeyId()
{
    var specialKeyId = "2591d7cfefrgrggr6bb90a19bedb9d42493";
    var extraSpecialAccessKey = "vXBx0PINNV2TEfsgffrgwaggfsQM0e6Epjc+1UJ0Y=";
    var clientSecurity = new ClientSecurity(new SignatureVersionFactory());
    var url = @"https://URL/TO/API";

    var uri = new Uri(url);

    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
    { 
        Content = new StringContent("{\r\n  \"appName\": \"Application Name 135543454\",\r\n  \"appDisplayName\": \"Application Display Name\"\r\n}", null, "application/json")
    };

    using var client = new HttpClient();
    
    await clientSecurity.SignRequestAsync(httpRequestMessage, specialKeyId, extraSpecialAccessKey, SigningAlgorithms.S3S);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    string statusMsg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

Comment: Please read the usage for the [api] tag: DO NOT USE THIS TAG.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 What tag do you mean sorry?

Comment: Get the full request in Postman which is obtained in the control panel.  You probably need additional http headers like user-agent.   The default headers in Postman are different from c#.  Postman also may be trying more than one type of authentication to make connection.  There is more than one type of authentication and Postman when one method fails tries with a second method.

Comment: @jdweng So where in the code should I place the header? In postmans there is an authrisation header request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "S3 14r4ff4f:8efeffffffffrfpr/e5Rd5O/dBcsU3/tK9hk7JOyyZU/lQmkuBQ73Z+w=");

Comment: @jdweng This is taken care of the internal nuget web security package

Comment: Are there additional headers like user agent or content-type?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858166/how-to-add-headers-to-a-httprequestmessage

Comment: @jdweng Not really they are hidden in Postman

Comment: I removed from your post the tag "api" to make the post compliant to guidelines. You then edited back in  again, making it now un-compliant.

Comment: Use the postman console like the answer with 327 points : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793629/postman-how-to-see-request-with-headers-and-body-data-with-variables-substitut

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Can’t see what you removed?

Comment: Guys FYI there is a web security nuget package which creates the appropriate access

Comment: Converting postman to C# doesn’t work because of this web security package hence syntax is different in this API